# ¿Cómo capturar el $action de un MERGE? TSQL / MS SQL Server 2019

Tags: sql-server

Tengo un problema, estoy haciendo uso de `MERGE` en un procedimiento almacenado:

```sql
MERGE MAN_InventarioRepuestos MIR 
        USING #temp_table_stock_almacen TXML 
        ON MIR.CodAlmacen = @CodAlmacenXML AND MIR.NroProducto = @NroProductoXML
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET MIR.CodAlmacen = TXML.CodAlmacen,
                MIR.NomAlmacen = TXML.NomAlmacen, 
                MIR.Empresa = TXML.Empresa,
                MIR.IdSucursal = TXML.IdSucursal,
                MIR.NomSucursal = TXML.NomSucursal,
                MIR.NroProducto = TXML.NroProducto,
                MIR.CodProducto = TXML.CodProducto,
                MIR.DescProducto = TXML.DescProducto,
                MIR.IdMarca = TXML.IdMarca,
                MIR.DescMarca = TXML.DescMarca,
                MIR.StockActual = TXML.StockActual,
                MIR.IdUnidadMedida = TXML.IdUnidadMedida,
                MIR.DescUnidadMedida = TXML.DescUnidadMedida,
                MIR.AbrevUnidadMedida = TXML.AbrevUnidadMedida
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
            INSERT (CodAlmacen,
                    NomAlmacen,
                    Empresa,
                    IdSucursal,
                    NomSucursal,
                    NroProducto,
                    CodProducto,
                    DescProducto,
                    IdMarca,
                    DescMarca,
                    StockActual,
                    IdUnidadMedida,
                    DescUnidadMedida,
                    AbrevUnidadMedida) 
            VALUES(TXML.CodAlmacen,
                TXML.NomAlmacen,
                TXML.Empresa,
                TXML.IdSucursal,
                TXML.NomSucursal,
                TXML.NroProducto,
                TXML.CodProducto,
                TXML.DescProducto,
                TXML.IdMarca,
                TXML.DescMarca,
                TXML.StockActual,
                TXML.IdUnidadMedida,
                TXML.DescUnidadMedida,
                TXML.AbrevUnidadMedida)
            OUTPUT $action;
```

Básicamente lo que deseo es obtener el valor de ese `$action` (que puede ser INSERT o UPDATE) fuera del `MERGE`, he intentado lo siguiente:

```sql
DECLARE @ACCION_ULTIMA VARCHAR(20)
SET @ACCION_ULTIMA = $action
```

Pero el mensaje que arroja es:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure uspMAN_AddStockAlmacen, 
Line 124 [Batch Start Line 7]
Invalid column name '$action'.
```

Claramente no me anda, espero puedan ayudarme!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**$Action** no es un valor escalar, se produce en cada una de las filas aceptadas por Merge y por tanto hay que realizar un tratamiento de conjuntos. Además es parte del output de la sentencia `Merge`. Y no separado de ella.

El output es un nvarchar(10) con uno de los siguientes valores:

- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE

Más info en [Merge](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

```
DECLARE @TABLEMERGE TABLE
(
Accion NVARCHAR(10),
CodAlmacen int,
NroProducto int
);

MERGE MAN_InventarioRepuestos MIR 
        USING #temp_table_stock_almacen TXML 
        ON MIR.CodAlmacen = @CodAlmacenXML AND MIR.NroProducto = @NroProductoXML
        WHEN MATCHED THEN 
            UPDATE SET MIR.CodAlmacen = TXML.CodAlmacen,
                MIR.NomAlmacen = TXML.NomAlmacen, 
                MIR.Empresa = TXML.Empresa,
                MIR.IdSucursal = TXML.IdSucursal,
                MIR.NomSucursal = TXML.NomSucursal,
                MIR.NroProducto = TXML.NroProducto,
                MIR.CodProducto = TXML.CodProducto,
                MIR.DescProducto = TXML.DescProducto,
                MIR.IdMarca = TXML.IdMarca,
                MIR.DescMarca = TXML.DescMarca,
                MIR.StockActual = TXML.StockActual,
                MIR.IdUnidadMedida = TXML.IdUnidadMedida,
                MIR.DescUnidadMedida = TXML.DescUnidadMedida,
                MIR.AbrevUnidadMedida = TXML.AbrevUnidadMedida
        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
            INSERT (CodAlmacen,
                    NomAlmacen,
                    Empresa,
                    IdSucursal,
                    NomSucursal,
                    NroProducto,
                    CodProducto,
                    DescProducto,
                    IdMarca,
                    DescMarca,
                    StockActual,
                    IdUnidadMedida,
                    DescUnidadMedida,
                    AbrevUnidadMedida) 
            VALUES(TXML.CodAlmacen,
                TXML.NomAlmacen,
                TXML.Empresa,
                TXML.IdSucursal,
                TXML.NomSucursal,
                TXML.NroProducto,
                TXML.CodProducto,
                TXML.DescProducto,
                TXML.IdMarca,
                TXML.DescMarca,
                TXML.StockActual,
                TXML.IdUnidadMedida,
                TXML.DescUnidadMedida,
                TXML.AbrevUnidadMedida)
            OUTPUT $action as MergeAction, 
                    inserted.codAlmacen, 
                    inserted.nroProducto 
                into @tableMerge; 

Select * from @TABLEMERGE;
```

Así puedes saber lo que se ha hecho en cada fila. He puesto codAlmacen y NroProducto como int, porque en la definición de la pregunta no se indica el tipo.

[Merge ¿Cómo se implementa?](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2019/10/04/merge-upsert-insertar-o-actualizar-en-una-sola-sentencia/)

Comment: Compañero, muchas gracias por la aportación, esa columna 'Accion' me sirvió para resolver mi problema a posteriori; básicamente lo que deseaba era conocer si se había insertado o actualizado con el MERGE. Excelente!